# Partial derivative is always equal to 0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following code to create a list of circles:

```
size = 7;
range = 30;
r = RandomReal[{.1, 6}, size];
loc = Table[
RandomReal[{-range + r[[i]], range - r[[i]]}, 2], {i, size}];
```

and then a function based on the distance from the other circles:

```
surf[x_, y_, j_] := -1/RegionDistance[
  RegionUnion[
    Table[
      Circle[loc[[i]], r[[i]]]
      , {i, Drop[Range[size], {j}]}
    ]
  ], {x, y}
]^2;
```

Now I want to get the partial derivatives at the location of each of the circles:

```
grad = Table[{D[surf[loc[[i, 1]], loc[[i, 2]], i], x], 
              D[surf[loc[[i, 1]], loc[[i, 2]], i], y]}, {i, size}]
```

but this always returns a list of {0,0}'s. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? The function is clearly not constant everywhere:

[image]

Comment: The values are plugged into `surf` before the derivative is taken.  Hence you're taking derivatives of constants.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe I understand the problem now but still don't know the solution. I tried replacing the grad with `grad[x_, y_, i_] := {D[surf[x, y, i], x], D[surf[x, y, i], y]}` and then evaluating at `grad[loc[[1, 1]], loc[[1, 2]], 1]`, but I get
`D(10.184)[-0.0025], D(-9.826)[-0.0025]` as the output. ({10.1,-9.8} is loc[[1]])

Comment: You probably want `ClearAll[grad]; grad[x_, y_, i_] := {Derivative[1, 0, 0][surf][x, y, i], Derivative[0, 1, 0][surf][x, y, i]}`.  Be sure to clear `grad`.  You also need clear `surf` and define it with [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999), `surf[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, 1] :=...`, since the expression seems not to be symbolically differentiable, but only numerically.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for this, I was not aware of this very helpful notation for Derivative. I'm using `Remove["Global*"] `to clear everything at the beginning of the notebook, so I believe it's not necessary to clear grad again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my way of fixing up the OP's functions:

```
ClearAll[surf];
surf[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, j_] := -1/RegionDistance[RegionUnion @@
      Table[Circle[loc[[i]], r[[i]]], {i, Drop[Range[size], {j}]}], {x, y}]^2;

ClearAll[grad];
grad[x_, y_, i_] := {Derivative[1, 0, 0][surf][x, y, i], 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][surf][x, y, i]}
```

And here's a speed improvement that factors the `Regions` because `surf` is very slow.  Also, it uses an order-2 approximation to the derivative instead of the built-in order-8 method that `Derivative` uses when it cannot do the derivative symbolically.

```
ClearAll[surf2];
surf2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, j_] := -1/Min[RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ 
      Table[Circle[loc[[i]], r[[i]]], {i, Drop[Range[size], {j}]}]]^2;

ClearAll[grad2];
grad2[x_, y_, i_] := 
  With[{dx = Max[Abs[x] Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon],
    dy = Max[Abs[y] Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon]},
   {(surf2[x + dx, y, i] - surf2[x - dx, y, i])/(2 dx), (
    surf2[x, y + dy, i] - surf2[x, y - dy, i])/(2 dy)}
   ];
```

And here's the difference in timing:

```
grad[loc[[1, 1]], loc[[1, 2]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {75.8591, {-0.00866156, -0.00262315}}  *)

grad2[loc[[1, 1]], loc[[1, 2]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.002797, {-0.00866156, -0.00262315}}  *)
```

The order-8 derivative used internally in `grad[]` with `surf2` instead of `surf`, takes about 25 times longer than the last one (`0.07` sec.).  It may be sufficiently fast.

***Update:***
I realized just before I had to leave that `surf2[]` could be symbolically differentiated if I removed the `?NumericQ`.  This is because `RegionDistance` evaluates to a symbolic expression on a simple circle but not on a union of them.  So here's the fastest way:

```
ClearAll[surf3];
surf3[x_, y_, j_] := -1/
   Min[ComplexExpand@RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ 
      Table[Circle[loc[[i]], r[[i]]], {i, Drop[Range[size], {j}]}]]^2;

ClearAll[grad3];
Block[{x, y}, (* protects x,y since we pre-evaluate the derivatives *)
 grad3[x_, y_, 1] = {D[surf3[x, y, 1], x], D[surf3[x, y, 1], y]};
 ]

grad3[loc[[1, 1]], loc[[1, 2]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.000364, {-0.00866156, -0.00262315}}  *)
```